# How can I use WatiN with the jQuery show and hide functions?

Tags: jquery, hide, watin, show

I have just using WatiN.  My company uses the jQuery show and hide functions to display error messages.  I want to make sure that these messages appear at the correct times. I have been using a test script from a jQuery download which uses show and hide. I added id values to the div tag and to one of the enclosed scan tags. I have been unable to detect in my code when the message is being displayed.

I have included below both both the jQuery script and my code.  The script has two buttons, one for displaying and one for hiding a message.  My code hits the hide button and examines the visibility and width attributes and then hits the show button and looks at the same attributes.  I can see on the screen that the text is indeed being hidden and then shown. When I set break points, in both cases the visibility is set to "inherited" and the width is set to "auto."  What can I do to distinguish between the two cases?

```
jQuery code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <style>
      span { background:#D8BFD8; padding:3px; float:left; }
      </style>
      <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <button id="hidb">Hide</button>
  <button id="showb">Show</button>
  <div id="dynamicOutput">

    <span id="jquery">jQuery</span> <span>is</span> <span>easy</span> 
    <span>to</span> <span>use</span> <span>and</span> 
    <span>gives</span> <span>dynamic output..</span>

  </div>

<script>
    $("#hidb").click(function () {
              $("span:last-child").hide("fast", function () {
    // use callee so don't have to name the function
        $(this).prev().hide("fast", arguments.callee); 
      });
    });
$("#showb").click(function () {
  $("span").show(2000);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>

Test code:

 [TestMethod]
        [STAThread]
        public void lookAtElements()
        {

              var browser = new IE("http://localhost/test/jqHIdeShowText.html");

               Element el2 = browser.Span(Find.ById("jquery"));  
               Element el = browser.Div(Find.ById("dynamicOutput"));

               string att;
               string att2;
               string width;
               string width2;
               string msg;
               string msg2;


               Button btn = browser.Button(Find.ById("hidb"));
               btn.Click();


               width = el.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
               width2 = el2.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");

               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

               el.Parent.Refresh();
               el.Refresh();
               el2.Refresh();

               width = el.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
               width2 = el2.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
               att = el.Style.GetAttributeValue("visibility");
               att2 = el2.Style.GetAttributeValue("visibility");
              msg = el.Text;
               msg2 = el2.Text;


               btn = browser.Button(Find.ById("showb"));
               btn.Click();
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

           el.Parent.Refresh();
           el.Refresh();
           el2.Refresh();

               att = el.Style.GetAttributeValue("visibility");
               att2 = el2.Style.GetAttributeValue("visibility");
               width = el.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
               width2 = el2.Style.GetAttributeValue("width");
               msg = el.Text;
               msg2 = el2.Text;

              browser.Close();


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) attribute instead:

```
if (el.Style.GetAttributeValue("display") == "none") {
    // The element was hidden through hide().
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What I needed this for was to see if error messages were being displayed associated with entry fields.  What I found was that if there was an error message, the parent entry of the entry field had a textbox containing the error message and if there was no error then there was no textbox.

Comment: Excellent :) Now you only have to post the relevant parts of your comment (maybe elaborating a little, as you see fit) in your own answer, then accept it. [This is allowed and actually encouraged in this situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).